# OptaPlanner, could PlanningVariable be set to null which is not in the range

Tags: optaplanner

optaplanner-bom 7.59.0.Final. In my PlanningEntity class Task there is a PlanningVariable and a CustomShadowVariable

```
@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "indexRange")
private Index index;
@CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = UpdatingVariableListener.class,
sources = { @PlanningVariableReference(variableName = "index") })
private Long d;
```

in the PlanningSolution class the range is referred:

```
@ProblemFactCollectionProperty
@ValueRangeProvider(id = "indexRange")
private List<Index> indexList;
```

the rule file is to minimize the sum of all "d"s:

```
rule
when
    accumulate(
        Task(index != null, $d: d);
        $s: sum($d)
    )       
then
    scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, 1, (int)(-$s));
end
```

in the afterVariableChanged() of the UpdatingVariableListener, by calling scoreDirector.getWorkingSolution(), I can see in the variable "indexList" there are two elements (let's call them "1" and "2") and none of them is java "null". When I set breakpoint in the afterVariableChanged(), with the first hit the "index" is "2", the second time it's "1", the third time is java "null". And noticed that for the second time and third time, the solution object are the same object. Do not think "null" should be set as it's not in the range. Anything wrong was done?

Comment: Is this in construction heuristics, or in local search? In CH, nulls are expected, as your solution is likely uninitialized. Also in CH, the solution objects are never cloned, so that'd also explain why you're seeing the same solution.

Comment: @Lukáš Petrovický  Thank you Lukáš. Understand that null is a normal case and I found that in docs. I'm not sure about construction heuristics or in local search, didn't specify anything about that. Because PlanningVariable "null" for sure is not a potential solution, may I do nothing in afterVariableChanged( ) when it's null?

Comment: If you haven't specified either CH or LS, that means a default config applies. Which in turn means a CH will run before LS. CH is there to create an initialized solution that LS can later pick up - in other words, it has to remove all the nulls first. But if you have variable listeners there, they need to be ready to see nulls, because at the start, before CH, variables are null.